# How to UPDATE from columns in an attached database in sqlite3?

Tags: database, sqlite

After 4 hours of googling and more hours of experiments pretty much my last hope is that someone can tell me what is going on when I try the following:

```
    sqlite3 test1.sqlite
    attach database 'test2.sqlite' as newDB;
```

This works - no error messages and ".databases" shows "newDB" as #2. "newDB" and "main" have exactly the same structure: same tables, same columns, same names for everything. Simple stuff like

```
    select * from main.ztip;
```

or

```
    select * from newDB.ztip;
```

works. ("ztip" being, obviously, a valid table name in both DBs.) But when I try to do what I need to do (omitting the WHERE clause for simplicity)

```
    update main.ztip set zisfavorite=newDB.ztip.zisfavorite;
```

BOOM! The column "newDB.ztip.zisfavorite" isn't found. Same goes for

```
    update main.ztip set zisfavorite=newDB.zisfavorite;
```

which I tried out of desperation. (Column names are unique.)

Anybody know whether what I want do is possible and how to make to work?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Because your previous command is for only displaying the data from newDB, not storing it!

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to update here.

You can use `UPDATE my_table SET col_a=col_b` when `col_a` and `col_b` are columns in the same table: this will update set value of `col_b` into `col_b` for each row. `col_b` isn't just a column name, but it's associated with a specific value in this case.

However, in `update main.ztip set zisfavorite=newDB.ztip.zisfavorite`, `newDB.ztip.zisfavorite` represents an entire column. There is no reason to know which row and value you're willing to use.

Perhaps you should use something like:

```
UPDATE main.ztip z1 SET zisfavorite=(SELECT z2.zisfavorite FROM newDB.ztip z2 WHERE z2.id=z1.id)
```

The details of the where clause will depend on the actual structure of your tables, of course. Make sure it returns only one value.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno. Sorry for the confusion about "what I want to update". I should have left the WHERE clause in place (where ztipid=7) to make it clear that that was not the problem.

Comment: Where is your `WHERE` clause? You'll need a `SELECT` to select a specific row/value from the other table.

Comment: Finally! This is the only answer I found anywhere that works!